# Hook length formulas relating sums over different partition sizes.

Tags: co.combinatorics

R.P. Stanley's and G-N. Han's work in 2008-2009 on Hook length formulas do not seem to connect sums over partitions of different sizes. 
I mean relations between sums over partitions of n-1, of n and of n+1.
I got one, but do not know if I should be surprised or not. It takes a better mathematician to distinguish between the boring and the interesting tidbits.

Since I'm a hopeless dud at LaTeX, forgive me replacing it with a link to a PDF file with the accompanying short Mathematica 4.0 notebook:

http://users.telenet.be/Wouter.Meeussen/MildlySurprisingHooks.pdf
http://users.telenet.be/Wouter.Meeussen/MildlySurprisingHooks.nb

Comment: I believe the papers being referenced are Han "Hook lengths and shifted parts of partitions" https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.1801 and Stanley "Some Combinatorial Properties of Hook Lengths, Contents, and Parts of Partitions" https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.0383.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow everything correctly, the Mathematica notebook
in the question conjectures that
$$
t (t+1) \sum_{k=0}^n
\frac{1}{n!}
\sum_{\lambda \vdash n}
 f(\lambda )^2  e_{n-k}(t + c_u^2 : u \in \lambda) =
\sum_{k=0}^{n+2}
\frac{(-1)^k}{(n+2)!}
\sum_{\lambda \vdash n+2}
f(\lambda )^2  e_{n+2-k}(t + c_u^2 : u \in \lambda)
 =
t (t+1)  \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}
(-1)^{k+n+1} t^{k-1} S_1(n+1,k)
$$
where $f(\lambda)$ is the number of SYT of shape $\lambda$, $c_u$ is the content,
$S_1$ is a Stirling number of the first kind, and $e_{j}(L)$
is the $j$th elementary symmetric function evaluated in $|L|$ variables, with the elements in $L$ as arguments.